# City Steward has died, how do I buy a house now?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After fighting with the Imperial side at the following quest:

> Battle for Whiterun

The town steward died. I didn't see him die per say, but once I went back in town, a courier came to me with an inhereitance letter saying that the town's steward had passed away.

The problem is, I didn't have the funds to buy the house earlier, and now I remembered that the Steward is dead. Is there any other way to buy an house after the steward has passed away?

---

I am playing on PC, however I'd prefer to get a solution that didn't involve using the console commands preferably (I'm trying to do a 0 commands run). Although I'll use the resurrect command if I absolutely must.

Comment: Which steward died? Brill or Proventus?

Comment: @pushasha Proventus.

Comment: What's wrong with the question to warrant a downvote? I'd appreciate some feedback / edit if needed

Comment: Are you playing on pc?

Comment: @Vahx Yes, however I'd prefer to not use console commands if possible

Comment: Proventus is only the steward while Whiterun is under Imperial control. During the Battle of Whiterun, if you side with the Stormcloaks then Brill will become the steward (if Brill died, then Proventus remains the steward)

Comment: After some research, I conclude that you are most likely screwed.

Comment: One possible solution, which requires a minimum of console usage, would be to load a save before he died and mark him as essential to prevent this problem; a solution to this problem would be to use console commands to locate his corpse and resurrect him; since you specifically asked for no console commands, i wont make this an actual answer.

Comment: @Vahx If there is no other solution **Without** using console commands, then I won't have any choice but to accept a solution with the commands. The savefile would've been my first thing to do but it was already too late

Comment: You should teleport to his corpse to see how he died, because he should be essential to begin with.

Comment: It turned out to be the game being goofy. He was alive (but stuck somewhere because I had to teleport him to me), furthermore the inheritance letter said that he died, but was signed by himself. Oh well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proventus should be essential. Maybe try teleporting him to you- unless you are using a mod that makes him unessential, he should be alive. Or just try waiting a few hours in dragons reach- he might yet turn up.

Comment: Forgot to reply to this somehow. Yes, this is the case. Somehow he wound up in a bedroom